# Rebound shift key still acts as shift key

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have rebound my right shift key (keycode 62) to act as the up arrow by replacing `Shift_R` in its keysym with `Up`:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode  62 = Up NoSymbol Up"
```

However when using the key, some applications (e.g. Firefox) still see it as a shift key - that is, when it is clicked it acts as *both* an up key and a shift key.

This means that when used in a textbox, instead of moving the cursor 1 line up, it moves the cursor 1 line up and highlights the text from the previous cursor position to the new cursor position, just like what would happen if you normally did <kbd>Shift + Up</kbd>.

How can I remove the <kbd>Shift</kbd> functionality from my right shift button, without removing it from the left shift key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run

```
xmodmap -e 'remove shift = Up'
```

before your cmd.